# What authorizing entity excludes your e-mail to be tagged as spam?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

Right now we have this project that periodically sends e-mails to more or less 16,000 people. These emails are work related and the recipients need these e-mails for their work.

I have read somewhere before that there is this authorizing entity that you register your e-mail to so that the internet will not tag it as spam despite sending a lot of e-mail in a short time.

I was wondering what authorizing entity is that so that the 'internet' will not tag our e-mail sender as spam.

Our current e-mail provider is Google as part of Google Apps for work, if that equates to anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are several email server blacklists out there. They each have their own rules that can have your email land on these lists. Popular mail clients will refer to these public mailing blacklists - as well as examine the content of the mail - to determine if you are sending spam or not.

Therefore, I do not believe there is a single agency that coordinates these blacklists.

It can be a tedious process to get off the various blacklists. You basically have to convince the more famous ones that you are not spam.

I found a list of some of them [here](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/email-blacklists/). You should find a 'Blocklist removal' section on each of them.

[This](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/site-development/how-to-get-removed-from-an-e-mail-blacklist/) and [that](https://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-removal) website explain some steps to get off of them. You can find more of them. For example, from the first link:

> To get off some lists, you don’t need to do anything; for others, you need to make some changes and prove that you’ve made those changes. The procedures are as varied as the lists themselves:
>
> - Your IP may automatically drop off the blacklist, or timeout, after a specific length of time, which may be a couple of weeks.
> - You submit a form on the list-holder’s website.
> - You make adjustment to your list management practices to tighten security and make it hard for spammers to use your server, then apply to be removed from the blacklist.
> - Change your ISP. If the dynamic IP addresses your ISP assigns you are compromised, changing your provider may be the most efficient way to get off and stay off blacklists.

You should also check [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/628126/google-marks-my-mail-as-spam).

Comment: I see, thank you. Is it easier to just get an separate and specialized e-mail service so that they will handle the white listing or will this still have the same outcome?